# Jquery event chaining

Tags: javascript, jquery

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451491/what-is-the-best-way-to-emulate-an-html-input-maxlength-attribute-on-an-html-text)

I don't want to litter my ready stuff waiting for a "click event" AND a "change event" AND a "mouseover event"  I want to have all that stuff in a single function or event.

Is is possible to chain the events together.  I want to capture not only a keyup, but also a click or a change in case the user isn't on the keyboard.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function () {
    setMaxLength();
    $("textarea.checkMax").keyup(function(){ checkMaxLength(this.id); } );
    $("textarea.checkMax").mouseover(function(){ checkMaxLength(this.id); } );
});
</script>
```

This works

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    setMaxLength(); 
    $("textarea.checkMax").bind("click mouseover keyup change", function(){checkMaxLength(this.id); } )
});
```

Comment: side note: the `language="javascript"` attribute is deprecated and unnecessary

Comment: As far as I know, the language attribute is only deprecated in html5.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you are looking for bind. Bind can wire multiple events to the same function using a single call instead of using a chain:

```
$("textarea.checkMax").bind("keyup mouseover", checkMaxLength);
```

Answer (score 5):

Anything that returns the jQuery object can be used to chain. In general, everything returns the jQuery object, so if the API doesn't explicitly say it doesn't, chances are that the particular method does return the jQuery object and can be chained.

In the case of events, yes, they do return the jQuery object and can thus be chained. [See Here](http://docs.jquery.com/Events)

In your case, you can make an external function that takes one parameter, the object that the event happened on, and then check the length of it, or whatever else you want to do. Then, you just call `mouseUp(myFunction).mouseOut(myFunction).keyPress(myFunction)` or whatever else you were looking to chain together.

Here is a more explicit example:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function () {
    setMaxLength();
    $("textarea.checkMax").keyup(checkMaxLength()).
        mouseover(checkMaxLength(this.id));
});
</script>
```

Comment: But I am waiting those events to happen.  I will clarify my question

Comment: Yes, since those functions bind event handlers, and then return the jQuery object, you can chain event bindings just fine.

Comment: Read the documentation available at jQuery.com. It explicitly states that these methods return the jQuery object.

Comment: Sorry if I am being dense, or maybe I don't understand the vocaburlary.  An example would be nice.

Comment: I wanted this I guess:  $("textarea.checkMax").bind("click mouseover keyup", function(e){checkMaxLength(this.id); } )