# Is it possible to chain multiple events with one function in jQuery

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery event chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451795/jquery-event-chaining)

Traditionally we may write:

```
    $("selector").click(function () {

    });
```

but is it possible to chain events, something like so:

```
    $("selector").click,keyup,keydown(function () {

    });
```

I'm aware of the fact that I could write a function and reference that function in three seperate handlers, but this would be cleaner.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind#multiple-events)

```
$("selector").bind("keyup keydown click", function () {

});
```

For jQuery 1.7 and later, using the new `API` [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) is more preferred

```
$("selector").on("keyup keydown click", function () {

});
```

Comment: the `(` before `function` is not supposed to be there. This works after the minor fix. Thanks

Comment: +1 - although, if you're using jQuery 1.7.x, you should use `.on()` instead of `.bind()`