# Multiple JavaScript functions on click in wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress plugin and need two functions to happen on onClick function on different ID's. I have code something like this.

```
echo "<div id='cnote_open'><a id='show-note' onclick='document.getElementById(&quot;website-link-          box&quot;).style.top=&quot;10%&quot;;return false;' >Show Notification</a></div>";
```

I want to include the below function for above `onClick`. I don't want a function to called `onClick` and include these two functions in it. I want to include this function in the above piece of code only.

```
onClick='document.getElementById(&quot;dvs_env&quot;).style.display=&quot;block&quot;;return false;'
```

Is there a way on including multiple JavaScript functions on different ids on a single click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this kind of stuff manually using "string" definition of your delegates don't sounds good. You should consider using a Javascript library like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/Events/) and then you should consider [event chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451795/jquery-event-chaining).

Both provided links should give you all information you need to achieve your target.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 -the only sensefully suggestion here -  And normally Wordpress ships with Jquery, so this should be really straight forward to use. Or bind the events your own with vanilla js.

Comment: The code I have given is in php function in the header.php file, as when the funtion is called it takes, If I include my jqury event change here its not showing up. Can I do something like this?        onclick='document.getElementById(&quot;website-link-box&quot;).style.top=&quot;10%&quot;;return false;' && 'document.getElementById(&quot;DVS_cnote_env&quot;).style.display=&quot;block&quot;;return false;'

Comment: I don't really understand why it will not work with jQuery. You probably have issue within your script. As hakre pointed this is really the way you should do it. Anyway I have fixed your statement if you keep want to do it this way : onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('website-link-box').style.top='1‌​0%';document.getElementById('DVS_cnote_env').style.display='block';return false;"