# Is it possible to bind multiple functions to multiple delegation targets in one place?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

As it is possible to define multiple event handlers in one single function in jQuery like this:

```
$(document).on({
    'event1': function() {
        //do stuff on event1
    },
    'event2': function() {
        //do stuff on event2
    },
    'event3': function() {
        //do stuff on event3
    },
    //...
});
```

Then again we can do this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickedElement', function() {
    //do stuff when $('.clickedElement') is clicked
});
```

I was wondering if it is also possible to do something like this (the following code does not work, it's just for illustration):

```
$(document).on('click', {
    '.clickedElement1', function() {
        //do stuff when $('.clickedElement1') is clicked
    },
    '.clickedElement2', function() {
        //do stuff when $('.clickedElement2') is clicked
    },
    //... and so on
});
```

This code gives me an error complaining about the "," after `'.clickedElementX'`. I also tried it like this:

```
$(document).on('click', {
    '.clickedElement1': function() {
        //do stuff when $('.clickedElement1') is clicked
    },
    //... and so on
});
```

Then I don't have the error but also the function is not executed. Is there a way to collect all the click handlers in one place like this or would I have to always do it like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickedElement1', function() {
    //do stuff when $('.clickedElement1') is clicked
});
$(document).on('click', '.clickedElement2', function() {
    //do stuff when $('.clickedElement2') is clicked
});
//... and so on
```

Comment: Maybe if you go for chaining?

Comment: Skimming the documentation, http://api.jquery.com/on/ , it's not possible. You can bind several event types to one selector (whether it be delegated or not), in one `on` call. But you cannot bind one event type to several selectors for delegation

Comment: Something around these lines? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451795/jquery-event-chaining

Comment: @MelanciaUK Hmm, no. That is binding multiple events to one element. I would like to listen for clicks on the document and then check the element in the dom that was clicked and the execute the bound function.

Comment: Got it. Quite trick then.

Comment: @lan, you are wrong. You can bind one event type to several selectors. See that: http://jsfiddle.net/EqYkv/

Comment: @IgorPatychenko - technically that is correct, you can bind an event handler to multiple elements, but not with different functions for each element (not counting filtering inside the function).

Comment: As a sidenote, I'd advice against binding all event handlers to the document, and then do a lot of filtering everytime the document is clicked, moused over etc. as it will be inefficient.

Comment: @adeneo, I know, but lan said: "But you cannot bind one event type to several selectors for delegation". Technically its posible, and its works. Obviously we need to filter inside the code, but this is the best way to bind the same event on different selectors.

Comment: event delegation for non dynamic elements is overrated in my opinion, and this just seems like a bad idea. Just write regular event handlers instead, there is nothing to gain from this, not in performance nor the amount of code needed.

Comment: @IgorPatychenko Sure, but you can't bind individual callbacks for each selector (I should've specified), which is what the OP is talking about. Your example shows one callback for all the selectors. But I don't see how that's related

Comment: @lan you're right about the fact that you can not bind different callbacks to several selectors. I misunderstood. My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain :

```
$(document).on({
    click: function() {
        //click on #test1
    },
    blur: function() {
        //blur for #test1
    }
}, '#test1').on({
    click: function() {
        //click for #test2
    }
}, '#test2');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uWmbQ/)

Comment: This is the setup that is closest to the OP's that makes sense. It's not exactly what they're asking for, but probably how it should be handled

Comment: @Ian - I thought so at least, but it's still generally a bad idea to bind everything to the document, as jQuery still has to filter out all events of that type happening on the document to see if the selector matches etc !

Comment: Absolutely! Hopefully this is just an example or a hypothetical question, and would be using a more specific container selector

Comment: I think so too – this is pretty close to what I want. But I think I will listen for the click events in a more specific context. The advantage (if it really is one) of the $(document).on('click',...) approach is that it also works outside of $(document).ready. If I would do  $('.clickElement').on('click', ...) I would have to call it inside the domready function to make sure $('.clickElement') is rendered so any click events on it would be recognized.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, you have to bind them all separately.

Long answer: You can create an "infrastructure" for your site and have all events in one place. e.g.

```
var App = function(){
  // business logic

  return {
    Settings: { ... },
    Events: {
      'event1': function(){
      },
      'event2': function(){
      },
      'event3': function(){
      }
    }
  }
}();
```

Then wiring it up involves:

```
$(document).on(App.Events);
```

Then internally you can add then new bindings to your `App` object but still remains wired up in only one place (as far as jQuery is concerned). You could then make some kind of subscriber model within `App` (e.g. `App.Subscribe('click', function(){ ... })`) and each new subscription still is only wired through the single `.on()` binding.

but, IMHO, this is a lot of overhead with very little pay-off.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click' , function(e){
 if($(e.target).hasClass("some-class")){
  //do stuff when .some-class is clicked
 }
 if($(e.target).hasClass("some-other-class")){
  //do stuff when .some-other-class is clicked
 }
});
```

you can choose any `some-class` you want

Comment: I guess this is somewhat close to what I want, if not that convenient as I would like it to be...

Comment: Because I unfortunately can only accept one answer and imo the one I accepted is a little closer to what I want. Your solution is close, too but you have to check inside an statement via an additional jQuery method what element was clicked. So I chose to accept the answer that had less "extra-stuff" to check the clicked element.

Comment: aaah Ok, I intended that mine solution was the closest, don't mind

Answer (score 0):

you can use a helper function:

```
function oneplace(all){
    for (var query in all){
        $(query).on('click', all[query]);
    }
}
```

and then call:

```
oneplace(
    {'#ele1':function(){
             alert('first function');
         },
     '#ele2':function(){
             alert('second function'); 
         }});
```

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5zwkf/

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done, really:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $(this).on('click', '.one, .two',function()
     {
         if ($(this).hasClass('one'))
         {//code for handler on .one selector
             console.log('one');
         }
         else
         {//code for handler on .two selector
             console.log('two');
         }
         console.log(this);//code for both
     });
 });
```

If multiple events is what you're after:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $(this).on('click focus', '.one, .two',function()
     {
         if (event.which === 'click')
         {
             if ($(this).hasClass('one'))
             {
                 console.log('one');
             }
             else
             {
                 console.log('two');
             }
         }
         else
         {
             console.log('focus event fired');
         }
         console.log(this);
     });
 });
```

Play around with this: [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kttkj/)

[documentation on event](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)
[jQuery's `on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), which is used here as though it were [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)