# Can input be limited to html <textarea>?

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to emulate an HTML input “maxlength” attribute on an HTML textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451491/what-is-the-best-way-to-emulate-an-html-input-maxlength-attribute-on-an-html-t)

My question is can a `<textarea >` be configured only to accept a certain number of characters? I can do this in the following JavaScript, but the person for whom I am designing this page does not want a status field.

My current way of doing things is I have a `<textarea >` that is part of a form that uses a nice JavaScript function to fill a message in a status box.

I also read SO and found Alerts and sounds really aren't the way to alert people, so the following code changes background color (and restores when appropriate) when there is an error.

Here is that code:

```
// Checks Form element TransDesc for overruns past 255 characters.
function warnOverDescLen()
{
  var misc_text  = 
  document.forms["InvGenPayTickets"]["TransDesc"].value;
  var alert_text = 
  "You cannot enter more than 255 characters. Please remove some information.";

  var rc = true;

  if(255 < misc_text.length)
  {
    document.forms["InvGenPayTickets"]["trans_status"].value 
      = alert_text;

    misc_text = misc_text.substring(0, 253);

    document.forms["InvGenPayTickets"]["TransDesc"].value 
      = misc_text;

    document.forms["InvGenPayTickets"]["trans_status"].style.backgroundColor 
      = "pink";
  }
  else
  {
    document.forms["InvGenPayTickets"]["trans_status"].value 
      = "";
    document.forms["InvGenPayTickets"]["trans_status"].style.backgroundColor 
      = "lightgoldenrodyellow";
  }

  return rc;
}

<textarea rows="4" cols="60" name="TransDesc" id="TransDesc" 
onkeypress="return warnOverDescLen();" ></textarea>

<span style="color: #50081E; font-weight: bold">Status</span>
<br />
<input type=text name="trans_status" id="trans_status" maxwidth="50"
size="65" />
```

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451491/what-is-the-best-way-to-emulate-an-html-input-maxlength-attribute-on-an-html-t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a solution for HTML5, not supported by IE9 or earlier (according to [this](http://wufoo.com/html5/attributes/03-maxlength.html)):

```
<textarea maxlength="255"></textarea>
```

Since you probably can't drop support for IE9 (and maybe even IE8), it's recommended you couple that with JavaScript, preventing the default behavior for the `keydown` and `paste` events on the textarea, as standup75 suggested.

Here is how to do that with plain JavaScript:

```
<textarea id="txtarea" maxlength="255"></textarea>
<script>
var field = document.getElementById('txtarea');
if(field.addEventListener) {
    field.addEventListener('keydown', enforceMaxlength);
    field.addEventListener('paste', enforceMaxlength);
} else {
    // IE6-8
    field.attachEvent('onkeydown', enforceMaxlength);
    field.attachEvent('onpaste', enforceMaxlength);
}

function enforceMaxlength(evt) {
   var maxLength = 255;
    if(this.value.length >= maxLength) {
        evt.preventDefault()
    }
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/snJwn/

Comment: Thanks. So, on the 256th character, input will stop?

Comment: Just a warning, and I'm not 100% sure, but I believe this is HTML5 only, and even then not all browser implement it (yes, that includes everybody's favourite, IE) (*Edit* I'm NOT the downvoter)

Comment: Why was this voted down? Maxlength I know does affect the display size, and for some of my fields, I needed to shorten them using maxlength.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus yes, it just stops. You may combine it with js for further feedback (like changing the background as you mentioned).

Comment: @octopusgrabbus: I think because `maxlength` isn’t supported by all browsers on the `<textarea>` tag. ([`maxlength` wasn’t added to `<textarea>` until HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/).)

Comment: @octopusgrabbus I deserved the downvote. I answered too fast, from my phone, and forgot about the support issue. Thanks for your edit and accept (feel free to accept a different answer if you wish, BTW). I just edited the answer further to make it more complete.

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 offers the maxLength attribute. Otherwise, you'd need some javascript, in jQuery, you'd do something like

```
maxLength = 50;
$("textarea").on("keydown paste", function(e){
  if ($(this).val().length>=maxLength) e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `maxlength="255"` (it specifies the maximum number of characters allowed in the  element.)

or you can also do this by the jquery [here](http://www.yelotofu.com/2009/12/jquery-textarea-max-length/) i found the tutorial

html

```
<textarea cols="30" rows="5" maxlength="10"></textarea>
```

jquery

```
jQuery(function($) {

  // ignore these keys
  var ignore = [8,9,13,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,46];

  // use keypress instead of keydown as that's the only
  // place keystrokes could be canceled in Opera
  var eventName = 'keypress';

  // handle textareas with maxlength attribute
  $('textarea[maxlength]')

    // this is where the magic happens
    .live(eventName, function(event) {
      var self = $(this),
          maxlength = self.attr('maxlength'),
          code = $.data(this, 'keycode');

      // check if maxlength has a value.
      // The value must be greater than 0
      if (maxlength && maxlength > 0) {

        // continue with this keystroke if maxlength
        // not reached or one of the ignored keys were pressed.
        return ( self.val().length < maxlength
                 || $.inArray(code, ignore) !== -1 );

      }
    })

    // store keyCode from keydown event for later use
    .live('keydown', function(event) {
      $.data(this, 'keycode', event.keyCode || event.which);
    });

});
```

[Live example](http://yelotofu.com/labs/jquery/snippets/textarea/)

Comment: @Travis its cool ... check this out now

Comment: @Travis Looks like Opera 11 and IE9 claimed support, but didn't actually. IE10 seems to have fixed it, and hopefully Opera 12 too.

Comment: @Travis now i have correct it so would you please remove your comment ??