# <textarea> character limit

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, maxlength

What is a *cross-browser* way to set the maximum number of characters in a textarea, using plain Javascript?  [`maxlength`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp) does not work for textareas on Opera and IE9 and below (though it works on all major browsers for inputs).

Once the character limit is reached, the textarea should not allow more characters to be entered.  Text pasted either with Ctrl+V or the right-click context menu should be cut off at the character limit.  This means a solution that uses only `onkey___` events is not sufficient.

Comment: [That may answer your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451491/what-is-the-best-way-to-emulate-an-html-input-maxlength-attribute-on-an-html-t)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate *functions* that will either truncate the *value* or prevent the *Event* under your conditions, and then add them as several different listeners for all the events you're interested in.

```
function snip(len) {
    return function (e) {e.target.value = e.target.value.slice(0, len);};
}
function prevent(len) {
    return function () {
        if (e.target.value.length >= len) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    };
}

var len = 5; // choose your length however you want

var textarea = document.getElementById('texta'), // get the node
    trunc = snip(len),
    prev1 = prevent(len),
    prev2 = prevent(len - 1);

textarea.addEventListener('change'  , trunc, true);
textarea.addEventListener('input'   , trunc, true);
textarea.addEventListener('keydown' , prev2, true);
textarea.addEventListener('keypress', prev2, true);
textarea.addEventListener('keyup'   , prev1, true);
textarea.addEventListener('paste'   , trunc, true);
```

The events may need to be attached differently in IE

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fad2A/)

Comment: I'll also point out that these as they are don't cause infinite loops because setting `value = value` doesn't trigger change/input events, but if you're making other changes it might do, so be careful.

Comment: Nice answer!  However, this erases text at the end rather than preventing input once max length is reached.  Rather than tinker to make it work, I'll just go with `maxlength`.  Who needs Opera and IE9 support anyway?  :P