# Can I change the max attribute of an input tag using a function?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm coming in from this post: [Input max equal to javascript variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813786/input-max-equal-to-javascript-variable) but it did not quite solve my issue. I'm currently working with Google's HTML Service and I need help with the case below...

If I have a `Code.gs` function like this: `var myVar = function() { var x=2; return (x+x); }`

... and then, inside my HTML file, I have an input tag written like this: `<input id... max=myVar>`

Would setting the `max` attribute like this: `.setAttribute("max", myVar)` successfully change that value based on the value returned from my custom function? Initial attempts are failing.

Comment: You should try it and tell us if it works or not :)

Comment: Please post your try and result. Or you can just post `code snippet` we can see how it is going. Thanks

Comment: Attribute `max` should be value not function. Just replace with `myVar()`. And in html , you can set `max` with function. And `setAttribute` will work as expected. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your `myVar` variable is supposed to get a result from `myFunction()` (located inside `Code.gs`), and you want use the result from the said function inside your HTML file, you will find that simply doing this will not work:

```
var myVar = function() { google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).myFunction()}
```

The above function will simply return `undefined`

In order to get the resultant value from `myFunction()`, and use it to change an input tag attribute inside your HTML file, you will have to write something like this:

```
function onSuccess(myVar) {
    document.getElementById(*yourID*).setAttribute(*yourTargetAttribute*, myVar);
}; google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).myFunction();
```

By doing this, we use the onSuccess callback function to store the result from `myFunction()`, after which we can easily use that result to change any attribute we like.
I hope this helps someone because it certainly solved a major issue for me.

**NOTE:** Whereas the answer by *Exceptional NullPointer* works in most cases, for my particular case, the answer I have provided here is the one that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it, but you there needs to be a few improvemens to your code:

- function() must be lower, javascript is case sensitive
- you have to add () after myVar to call it as a function
- max will be checked when the form is submitted

```js
var myVar = function() { var x=2; return (x+x); }

document.querySelector("#myInput").setAttribute("max", myVar());
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" id="myInput" max>
  <button>send</button>
</form>
```