# What is the clearist notification method for html5 maxlength, or is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html

If I have for example inputs...

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10">
<textarea maxlength="20"></textarea>
```

How would I tell my user, they "have a limit of..." only when attempting add the 11th or 21st char respectively?

Is there an "html" way of handling this, or do we require javascript.

Comment: Other than the placeholder attribute, you'd need to use JS.

Comment: And if you want to implement it using JS, here's a good place to get started. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451491/what-is-the-best-way-to-emulate-an-html-input-maxlength-attribute-on-an-html-t?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could to a certain extent use the pattern attribute. For a maxlength of 10 you would write `<input type="text" pattern=".{0,10}" />`.

Now you would have to display the error message via CSS with help of the `:invalid`-selector.

[Here is an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/9m8xtzdu/1/)

Edit: This doesn't seem to be working with textarea, though … I am having a look into it right now.

Comment: I am playing with your fiddle, and still trying to enter that 11th char, without allowing it to be entered (keeping) the limitation and still having a warning. Your use of CSS deserves an up-vote!

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted that message instead of it not being allowed (you cannot submit the form with more than 10 characters, if that is enough?). I don't think that is possible, then. Also textareas suck :D

Comment: Yeah, we already have handled this in JavaScript previously. Using "html" was the new option, but wanted to add a warning using strictly "html".