# How to limit the size of an HTML textarea with JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, html, textarea

Anyone have code to limit the characters in a text field and display the character count?

I need something like twitter status input and I can't find anything online.  If there isn't anything out there, I'll probably make a jQuery plugin or at least open source this thing.

Thanks!

Comment: <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378294/what-is-the-best-way-to-limit-the-amount-of-text-that-can-be-entered-into-a-text">Check Here</a> and <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451491/what-is-the-best-way-to-emulate-an-html-input-maxlength-attribute-on-an-html-te/451797#451797">here</a>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this page:

[Interactive character limit for textarea using Jquery](http://www.ajaxray.com/blog/2007/11/09/interactive-character-limit-for-textarea-using-jquery/)

```
 <script language="javascript">
 function limitChars(textid, limit, infodiv)
 {
     var text = $('#'+textid).val(); 
     var textlength = text.length;
     if(textlength > limit)
     {
         $('#' + infodiv).html('You cannot write more then '+limit+' characters!');
          $('#'+textid).val(text.substr(0,limit));
          return false;
     }
     else
     {
      $('#' + infodiv).html('You have '+ (limit - textlength) +' characters left.');
      return true;
     }
 }
 </script>
```

Then bind the function to the keyup event of your textarea. Do this in jQuery’s ready event of document like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#comment').keyup(function()
    { 
        limitChars('comment', 20, 'charlimitinfo'); 
    })
});
```

Comment: I ended up using this one which looks very close to twitter: http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/enforceform.shtml